# allow to save empty value for dropdown attribute while importing products through csv in magento2 import

Tags: magento2, import

while importing products in magento2 given feature,my csv has empty values for some columns like gender which are not required case which has to be updated to empty value if empty value exists in CSV file.
 can anyone suggest me how do this with default magento2 import feature.

Comment: The attributes shouldn't be required,. If this attributes are required, you should have always an attribute for it.
Just change the required of the attribute on your attribute set.

Comment: @ntzz sorry edited my question

Comment: as far as i understand, if your attribute for example "gender" isn't required, you should could import the product with the column empty.
Check the attributes on Stores->Attributes->Products and select gender for example, check it isn't required.

Comment: @ntzz already made the gender value as not required,but when updated from csv with empty value,its not updating with empty value

Answer (score 3):

found the solution 
commented the below line in abstractype file in the model catalog product import.
//$rowData = $productTypeModel->clearEmptyData($rowData);

hope this helps other anyone facing the same problem